# Tabwidget dividers on Gingerbread vs ICS and above

Tags: android, tabwidget

I've created a tabs with fragments using TabWidget with custom layout for each tab. Everything seems to work and look fine except for one thing. On ICS and above it looks like the following:

[image]

But on Gingerbread it looks like the following:

[image]

As you can clearly see, in gingerbread the dividers are missing.

So I have two questions. First of all, is there anyway I can make dividers appear on Gingerbread? I have tried various suggestions on stackoverflow but they just don't want to show up.

Secondly, is there anyway to customize the look of the dividers? I have tried using:

```
setDividerDrawable()
```

with images which works on ICS but **I get a null pointer exception in Gingerbread.** 
(UPDATE: regarding the bolded issue, I just found out something really annoying. It seems that Gingerbread and ICS+ deal with dividers differently. I was getting a Null pointer exception at a TabWidget.getChildAt() call. When a divider is set, in Gingerbread the divider is considered as a child view of the Tabwidget it is contained in but it is NOT (or it is getting ignored) in ICS+. Hence the index I'm using for getChildAt is completely wrong in Gingerbread as the tabwidget is seeing 5 children (3 tabs and 2 dividers) but in ICS it is seeing only 3 (only 3 tabs))

Also I have tried setting the color of the dividers but they seem to not work at all.

Here is how the tabs are setup:

```
/**
 * Setup the tab host.
 */
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    this.tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    this.tabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    addTab( this,
            this.tabHost,
            this.tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_DASHBOARD).setIndicator(LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.tabview_dashboard, null)),
            (tabInfo = new TabInfo(TAB_DASHBOARD, MonitoringTab.class.getName(), args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    //create alert list and alert details fragments, add alert list to the tab bar
    tabInfo = new TabInfo(TAB_ALERT_DETAILS, AlertDetailTab.class.getName(), args);
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    tabInfo = new TabInfo(TAB_ALERTS, AlertListTab.class.getName(), args);
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    addTab( this,
            this.tabHost,
            this.tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_ALERT_SHOWING).setIndicator(LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.tabview_alerts, null)),
            tabInfo);
    this.mapTabInfo.put(TAB_ALERT_SHOWING, tabInfo);

    addTab( this,
            this.tabHost,
            this.tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_ERRORQUEUE).setIndicator(LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.tabview_errorqueue, null)),
            (tabInfo = new TabInfo(TAB_ERRORQUEUE, ErrorMessagesTab.class.getName(), args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    // Default to first tab
    onTabChanged(TAB_DASHBOARD);
    this.tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}
```